# PHP Fatal error: Class 'ProtocolBuffers\Message' not found in

Tags: php, ubuntu, protocol-buffers

I follow all steps from GitHub and worked well for me. I got stuck to make it load on my php, can u guys help me with that?

i did:

```
git clone https://github.com/chobie/php-protocolbuffers.git
cd php-protocolbuffers
phpize
./configure
make
make install
# please add following line to your php.ini
# extension=protocolbuffers.so
i tried run that in my project and i get that line:
```

i am doing a volunteer job, so i am trying run that website in my localmachine and pb is one of the dependecies, i contact one of the developers and he said its because i am not loading that on my php.ini , but the line is there so he said have no idea what is going on.

the error:

> [12-Jun-2015 10:49:33 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'ProtocolBuffers\Message' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/Common/protobufs/models/MembershipRequest.php
>   on line 22

looks like i am not loading that module on my php.ini but i inserted the line there, i tried many times but i got stuck, can u guys help me?

Comment: I assume you added the line `# extension=protocolbuffers.so` to php.ini **without** the leading hash (e.g. `extension=protocolbuffers.so`) ?

Comment: hello, yeah # is a comment, so i just inserted: extension=protocolbuffers.so  and still not working

Comment: Heh - thought I'd just hit the obvious gotchas first ... did you reboot Apache after changing php.ini?

Comment: yeah i did, i am not understand that protocolbuffers at all, i just need that running in the project is a dependence :(

Comment: You're on a Mac which is a bit outside my area of expertise but it should be the same as *nix I'm guessing... this article might help : http://jellystyle.com/2012/12/installing-php-extensions-with-mamp : the error message implies that the extension wasn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

well i just insert extension=protocolbuffers.so in the end of my php.ini file and after that started load :)

i don't know why if insert in the middle or another part of my php.ini will make it not load, if somebody know why, please just write here too.

thanks a lot for all help.